.mysql_history: how to persist it with the official MariaDB Docker image?
How does it work the MariaDB .mysql_history file from the official MariaDB Docker image?
It's not really something I want in production. But it might be handy in a developer setup. Also, although it is useless, I would like to understand what is going on!
Reproducible Example
Let's take the official mariadb:10-jammy Dockerfile:
https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/81c4ce79659a9b705686b5704a3f3d3b9119532a/10.11/Dockerfile
Let's use a simple Docker Compose file to implement a simple mariadb service:
version: "3.9"
services:
  mariadb-service:
    image: "mariadb:10-jammy"
    volumes:
       - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MARIADB_DATABASE
      - MARIADB_USER
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD

volumes:
  mariadb-data:

Let's create a simple .env file:
MARIADB_DATABASE=test
MARIADB_USER=toast
MARIADB_PASSWORD=secret
MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=socrat

Let's run a simple mariadb interactive command line session:
docker-compose up -d

. ./.env

docker-compose exec mariadb-service \
  mariadb --user "$MARIADB_USER" -p"$MARIADB_PASSWORD" "$MARIADB_DATABASE"

Let's run some commands, successfully, and let's use the keyboard "up arrow key" (↑) to find and run already-executed SQL commands.
Let's quit and execute again, successfully, the above command, and successfully find commands from your MariaDB history, etc.
Let's run docker compose down and docker compose up -d successfully, to access your data again.
Problem:
At this point, I the old MariaDB history is not available anymore.
(Data, instead, is still there, successfully.)
Question:
How to also persist the MariaDB shell history, in the official MariaDB container?

What I already tried:

Note that the official MariaDB Dockerfile has a useradd -r -g mysql mysql --home-dir /var/lib/mysql so I assumed the MariaDB CLI history file was set in the $HOME directory of the mysql user, so, in /var/lib/mysql/.mysql_history, so I assumed that file should be already persisted in my Docker volume (since I have a mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql) but that history file is never created there.

Thanks for any tip to understand how the MariaDB history file works inside this container.

Pay attention to the official MariaDB Dockerfile. If the official Dockerfile does not have an explicit USER, it means it runs as root (not mysql as you may think).
So, the container is really executed by root. So, its home is $HOME. So, the MariaDB CLI history file is set in /root/.mysql_history as default. You can double-check with this: docker-compose exec mariadb-service whoami that clearly says root.
In short, your Docker compose should be something like this, to persist the history file:
version: "3.9"
services:
  mariadb-service:
    image: "mariadb:10-jammy"
    volumes:
       - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
       - mariadb-root-home:/root
    environment:
      - MARIADB_DATABASE
      - MARIADB_USER
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD

volumes:
  mariadb-data:
  mariadb-root-home:

So: make sure to also create a Docker volume for /root, otherwise /root/.mysql_history is lost.
Don't be confused with the mysql user that, instead, is only used to instantiate the in-Docker server (not the in-Docker client) with some entrypoint tricks (see official MariaDB Docker entrypoint for Ubuntu jammy).
So, in the above example:

mariadb-data is designed to persist server data
mariadb-root-home is designed to persist your client MariaDB history

